# Copy paste format from sheet1 to new additional sheet

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sample1")
    ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
End Sub
```

However, the problem is whenever I change sheet name, the code wouldn't run anymore. So I decide to use the sheet codename which is Fixedtemplate(template)

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Fixedtemplate
    ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
End Sub
```

There is still

> compile error: Method or data member not found

Comment: Lim, where do you set the Fixedtemplate in the code, at the moment, it would be blank. You need to set ws1 = worksheets("Fixestemplate")

Comment: hi ! even after i set the set, there is still error msg on the subscript out of range

Comment: Subscript out of range likely that the sheet does not exist in the workbook

Comment: Basically, you need to set the object that points to your worksheet as a worksheet that exists in your workbook

Comment: please check out the image i have attached

Comment: I see 2 issues:  1) the image you posted does not show a sheet with codename `Fixedtemplate` 2) `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)` counts sheets in the ActiveWorkbook.  Try `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code works below for me, you will need to provide either the name or the number of the sheet in order to copy the data.

```
Sub main()
    Call Copydata("Fixedtemplate")
End Sub

Sub Copydata(name As String)
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(name)
    ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
End Sub
```